# Redirect to Wildcard Route Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

How would I post to a wildcard route?
I have a wildcard route which has a forum on it. This is the route for that wildcard route:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'purchase'], function()
{
    Route::get('/',[
        'as' =>'purchase',
        'uses' => 'PurchaseController@getPurchase'
    ]);

    Route::get('/{id}', array(
        'as'=>'id',
        'uses'=>'PurchaseController@getItemView'
    ));

});
```

and after the user submits the form from that view, I'm trying to get it posted to the same page with any errors, if any. Here is the post route:

```
Route::post('/purchase/{id}', array(
    'as'=>'purchase-post',
    'uses'=>'PurchaseController@postPurchaseCheck'
));
```

But I checked the action route for the form and it looked like so:

```
public/purchase/%7Bid%7D
```

instead of

```
public/purchase/wildcard
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you have defined the route with the {id}, but you are not assigning one when the form is created.

You should open your form like this:

```
{{ Form::model($model, ['route' => ['purchase-post', $model->id]]) }}
```